# Creating and populating a DataTable dynamically in JSF2.0

Tags: java, web-services, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I've a little problem right there. When I want to populate DataTable in JSF I have to create a model first, then use it in my view. Like on Primefaces sample [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableBasic.jsf).

And now, I have to create DataTable that will display data, that came from webservice. I don't know how many columns there will be, and I don't know their names... Could you recommend some wise solution ?

PS. I don't know also how to returned data from webservice - it is still to determine.

---

EDIT

```
public Bean() {
    columns = new ArrayList<String>();  
    rows = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();         
    populateColumns(columns,4);   

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++)  
    {               
        Map<String,Object> m = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        m.clear();          
        for(int j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++)  
        {
            m.put("Column" + j, "sth" + j + i);
        }                                               
        rows.add(m);
    }       
}

private void populateColumns(List<String> list, int size) {  
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)  
        list.add("Column" + i);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Collect the data in a `List<Map<String, Object>>` which represents the `rows` property. The `Map` represents the columns, keyed by a column name (if necessary, just autogenerated such as `column1`, `column2`, `column3`, etc by `"column" + i`). Collect those column names in a separate `List<String>` which represents the `columns` property. Finally show it as follows by `<p:columns>`:

```html
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.rows}" var="row">
    <p:columns value="#{bean.columns}" var="column">
        #{row[column]}
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: great.. Thanks, but how to get column header? Here is my bean in Question's EDIT. Only headers are missing.

Comment: Use `<p:columns headerText="#{column}">`. Or if you have header names in a separate `Map<String, String>`, then something like `<p:columns headerText="#{bean.headers[column]}">`

Comment: Thanks again. First option works fine. But second... I declare headers like that: List<Map<String, String>> headers; Create getter and setter with public, but headerText="#{browserBean.headers[column]}" doesn't work :/

Comment: When I write: headerText="#{browserBean.headers[2]}" I get in column: {c2=Column name 2}, where c2 is my column id..

Comment: Why do the headers need to be like that? Use `Map<String,String>` or `List<String>` instead. Otherwise you need an odd `#{browserBean.headers[2][column]}`.

Comment: @BalusC I am trying to create similar datatable from bean, this the code I have so far `table = new DataTable();
        table.setVar("row");
        table.setValue("#{bean.rows}");
        Columns cols = new Columns();
        cols.setValue("#{bean.columns}");
        cols.setVar("column");` But I am not sure how to set the inner text `#{row[column]}`. Can you please help

Comment: Well I did it by following this link :)    http://gerardnico.com/wiki/language/java/dynamic_data_table

Comment: @vishnuviswanath: bad article. Carefully read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used

Comment: @BalusC Thank you. I will check the link.