# Iterate over hashmap in jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am stuck at this for the last couple days. I have a bean which has an `HashMap` whose map values are `objects`. I am trying to iterate over the map by converting it to list.

If I do something like this
In bean

```
List<Map.Entry<String, List<Objects>>> entrySet = new ArrayList<…>map.EntrySet();
```

And in xhtml:

```
<p:datatable var=”obj” value=”#{bean.entrySet}”>>
  <p:columnGroup>
    <p:row>
      <ui:repeat var=”values” value=”#{obj.value}”>
          <p:column headerText=”#{values.xyz}” />
      </ui:repeat>
   <p:row>
  </p:columnGroup>
</p:datatable>
```

It shows an empty column

However, if I do something like this:
In bean

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

And in xhtml:

```
<p:datatable>
…
   <ui:repeat var=”values” value=”#{bean.list}”>
   …
   </ui:repeat>
…
</p:datatable>
```

It works. What I don't understand is that the value of hashmap is the list of objects. If I iterate over the values which is a list, why didn't it work?

I would really appreciate if someone can tell me what's wrong with my first approach. I can use the second one but it going to require major changes in the bean.

I have already seen below questions but couldn’t resolve my issue

[How to show hashmap values in jsf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001743/how-to-show-hashmap-values-in-jsf)

[Primefaces static and dynamic columns in datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25658034/primefaces-static-and-dynamic-columns-in-datatable)

[Creating and populating a DataTable dynamically in JSF2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970285/creating-and-populating-a-datatable-dynamically-in-jsf2-0/13970491#13970491)

[How to display variable number of columns in primefaces datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867345/how-to-display-variable-number-of-columns-in-primefaces-datatable)